# Concatenating PHP strings from an iteration

Tags: php, string, dictionary, iteration, concatenation

I'm working on some Database functions and, for some reason, I made two functions to make simple inserts/selects with arrays passed as arguments to a php function. The problem starts here.

```
    // basic database functions, to aid the development :D
    static public function Insert($table, $items = array())
    {
        if(is_array($items) == false)
        {
            return false;
        }

        $header = 'INSERT INTO ' . $table . '(';
        $values = 'VALUES(';

        $count = count($items) - 1;
        $cur = 0;

        foreach($items as $key => $value)
        {
            $num = is_numeric($value);

            $header .= $key . ($cur < $count) ? ', ' : ' ';
            $values .= (($num) ? '' : '\'') . $value . (($num) ? '' : '\'') . (($cur < $count) ? ', ' : '');

            $cur ++;
        }

        $header .= ')';
        $values .= ')';

        self::Query($header . $values);
    }

        $pair = array('id' => null,
                      'name' => Database::EscapeString((string)$xml->ID),
                      'avatar_url' => Database::EscapeString((string)$xml->Avatar),
                      'personal_msg' => Database::EscapeString((string)$xml->AboutMe),
                      'level' => (int)$xml->Level,
                      'progress' => (int)$xml->Progress,
                      'trophies_total' => (int)$xml->Trophies->Total,
                      'trophies_platinum' => (int)$xml->Trophies->Platinum,
                      'trophies_gold' => (int)$xml->Trophies->Gold,
                      'trophies_silver' => (int)$xml->Trophies->Silver,
                      'trophies_bronze' => (int)$xml->Trophies->Bronze,
                      'country' => Database::EscapeString((string)$xml->Country->Culture),
                      'is_plus' => (string)$xml->Plus,
                      'points' => (int)$xml->LevelData->Points,
                      'floor' => (int)$xml->LevelData->Floor,
                      'ceiling' => (int)$xml->LevelData->Ceiling,
                      'game_completion' => (double)$xml->GameCompletion,
                      'background_color' => ((int)$xml->Background->R << 16) | ((int)$xml->Background->G << 8) | ((int)$xml->Background->B),
                      'jid' => (string)$xml->jid
                      );

        Insert('profiles', $pair);
```

The data that the query contains is not correct:

```
INSERT INTO profiles(, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , )VALUES('', 'AlmamuPP', 'http://static-resource.np.community.playstation.net/avatar/3RD/30004.png', 'EVE Online & DUST fan', 2, 17, 12, 0, 0, 6, 6, 'ES', 'false', 270, 200, 600, 12.5, 458759, 'AlmamuPP@a4.es.np.playstation.net')
```

As you may notice, it just ignores all the keys in the dictionary, but the funny fact is that if I add

```
echo $key;
```

in the foreach the keys are printed as they should... Any idea about what could be hapening there and a way to fix it?

Comment: Your code is extremely vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: If you havent noticed yet, every data in the array is already escaped with some mysql functions (Database::EscapeString).

Comment: At a guess the precedence ordering between the ternary operator and the join operator is not what you expect.

Try: `$header .= $key; ($cur < $count) ? $header.=', ' : $header.='';`

Comment: Except for `$xml->Plus` and `$xml->jid`

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the expression on `()`? Like `$header .= $key . (($cur < $count) ? ', ' : ' ');`

Comment: Yeah, just noticed that, xDDD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing parenthesis:

```
$header .= $key . (($cur < $count) ? ', ' : ' ');
```

Like this it will work.

Comment: You are right. The solution proposed by Philip Whitehouse also works. Guess I have to get used to PHP stuff like that ._.